# C# WinForm 3.5 DataGridView Column Autosize Margin

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autosize

I have a C# 3.5 WinForm project, and I can't find where to adjust Margin used for a DataGridView's Header AutoSize.

AutoSizeColumnsMode is set to None.
I can resize the column larger or smaller, then double click to AutoResize, and it pops to this width, using the margin illustrated by my awesome paint skills:

[image: DataGridView Header Margin]
How can I adjust the margin used?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: [C# AutoSize DatagridView Populated By Linq Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816555/c-autosize-datagridview-populated-by-linq-query)

Comment: I have autosizing working- I want to adjust the margin used by autosizing.

Answer (score 0):

**"I want to adjust the margin used by autosizing"**

The property used to set a DataGridView's Margin Column size is slightly less obvious:

```
DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 41;
```