# AutoResize Not Working Properly When ColumnHeader Is Longest String

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

`dgvSampled.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);`

I'm trying to size the columns with the `AllCells` mode. The problem is that when the longest string in the column is the header, a buffer is left over.

Compare the `Requested` column to the `Coil #` column. Why does the `Coil #` column size itself perfectly to its content, but the `Requested` column sizes itself too large for its header title?

After making the columns unable to be sorted, they are now being sized as I expected them to be in the first place.

[image]

Comment: The header is considered part of the column and the autoresize includes it in determining the column size. That is why the "Thickness" column does the same.

Comment: But why does it size to the `Coil #` data perfectly (IE, no whitespace on either side), but leave whitespace on the end of the `Requested` header?

Comment: the data in the column is larger than the header. The autoresize will format to the largest cell whether it is the header or the data cell, the resizing does not care. If you know the largest size of the data cell, then you can always manually set the column width.

Comment: What I'm saying is that, when the largest cell is in the header, it doesn't shrink as much as it could. The `Requested` column could be sized significantly smaller than it is right now, but the `Coil #` column could not be sized any smaller without the data being clipped.

Comment: If the column is sortable, there is some place on the left of the header for the down/up arrows. Note that sometimes the AutoColumnSize does not take into account all rows, specially those located out of visible window.

Comment: I agree, and I have found it to be quite annoying when there are a large number of columns. It seems that the resizing includes some amount of margin whether you like it or not, which can affect the size of whole table.

Comment: Ah! I haven't thought of the sorting arrows. I wonder if there's a way to disable sorting, and if that would fix my problem.

Comment: Each column has a SortMode property.  Set them to NotSortable.

Comment: @Graffito Thank you very much. The sorting arrow was causing the margin.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> AllCells: The column widths adjust to fit the contents of all cells in the columns, **including header cells**.

From your description, it seems that what you want is `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader`

Comment: No that's not what I want. I want the column's width to shrink to fit the longest string in the column (including the header). What I have now is working when the longest string is not in the header (note the lack of whitespace in the `Coil #` data). When the longest string is in the header (`Requested`), whitespace is left on at the end in the header title.

Comment: That is exactly what your code is doing as is right now. I guess you're concerned about the right-margin being larger in the header than it is in the cell itself? There might be a way to override the default on that, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Yes, I am concerned about the right-margin. I thought there might be some padding being added, or that the alignment might be adding something, but so far neither of those avenues have been fruitful.

Comment: Gotcha. I understand now. I thought maybe you could change the padding on the ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle property, but it looks like that is already set to 0 anyway. I'm not sure there's a way to override the margin being added there. Looks like someone else asked the same thing and didn't get an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528552/c-sharp-winform-3-5-datagridview-column-autosize-margin